# Can glGetError block a thread?

Tags: opengl

I develop a safety critical application which must work at 30 frame per second.
In case it is not able to provide the 30fps or any other error happens we draw black screen instead.

I'd like to query the error flag by a glGetError call as often as it is feasible, but I afraid it can block the drawing thread for a longer time (for a few ms).

Can the glGetError call block the thread until the latest opengl command has not been processed?

If no, how do I know if there was an error during the execution of the the latest opengl command?

Technical parameters:
- Linux 2.6.20-1.21 
- Nvidia Quadro NVS 285
- libGL.so.100.14.19

Comment: If you designed your application to behave correctly (in OpenGL correctness terms), you probably don't need to check for GL errors (unless you execute an user-input GL commands). Stress-test your application on debug stage to check all possible GL errors, then omit those checks on production stage. If GL error happens it would then probably mean the hardware failure.

Comment: Thanks. But I am still interested in the behavior of the glGetError command since the specification is not 100% clear.

Comment: I think there will be no specification that provides the exact (or guaranteed, or at least, average) time which `glGetError` spends. The function obviously dives inside the driver's guts and queries the internal flags. Since OpenGL contexts are one-per-thread, there are per-thread sets of flags. You might consider a time cost of a ring3->ring0 and back switch as a minimum possible estimate of a glGetError timing.

Comment: Not so funny thing is: this is happening to me [OpenGL: glGetError() halts current Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855543/opengl-glgeterror-halts-current-thread)
I believe this is unfixable though, so I am starting my application twice programmaticaly and choose the one process which has an initialised window.
I found this post in the "Related" section here on stackoverflow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing in the GL specification guarantees *anything* regarding blocking (or performance characteristics for that matter).

Now, glGetError for most implementations I've seen actually works without any interaction with the GPU hardware, just the API part of the driver side. In short, it ought not to block (caveat: implementation detail).

As a side note, the various places where a GL error ought to be generated and checked on the GPU, the specification pretty much says the behavior is undefined as opposed to error-generating, specifically to not have this issue.

Finally, glxSwapBuffer will more likely be a place where you'll see blocking happen, because your GPU is still busy drawing previous frames (so the drivers usually pick that point to make sure the CPU does not get too far ahead).

Comment: In fact, I have seen glGetError() working in another thread. It did not clear the error though, so that was a problem. Indeed, implementation dependent.

Comment: The only time I've seen glGetError not clear the error is when you call it without having a current context, i.e. glGetError itself returns GL_INVALID_OPERATION.